# Video screen captures

Tags: video

How can I take pictures of a video like the example below? Which software do I need to use, free if possible?

[image]

Answer (score 3):

Although a lot of software can do this, the one they used in particular is shown on the top right of the photo, they used [Media Player Classic](http://sourceforge.net/projects/guliverkli/) which is free :)

The feature is under **File -> Save Thumbnails**.

Answer (score 0):

You can [try screen video recorder software](http://www.dvd-creators.net/screen-capture/windows-screen-capture.html) to take pictures. I used a easy-to-use screen capture tool.

Answer (score 0):

Using ordinary screen-capture software can be tricky because DirectX overlays often do not appear in the result. However, by turning off DirectX acceleration temporarily in the Troubleshooting section of your video settings (a slider), you can then use any snapshot tool.

But it is far easier to use a video player with a built-in snapshot tool.